# Doctrine2 - No Metadata Classes to process

Tags: doctrine-orm

Something is wrong with documentation or me. I do all what documentation says.

When i put in terminal :

```
$ php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
```

Output is :

```
No Metadata Classes to process
```

I read to many posts, and google and try to many examples but nothing.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html

Comment: Did you add the Product entity? http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html#starting-with-the-product After you add the Product.php entity and metadata (I'd recommend using annotations in the entity class, which is the "php" tab in the example code) you will be able to run the `orm:schema-tool:create` command successfully — the tutorial is not clear about this, so you're not doing anything wrong.

Comment: Use this tutorial: https://rapidsol.blogspot.com/2017/12/tutorial-doctrine-2-linux.html

Answer (score 110):

I think you took the config example from [Doctrine2: getting started](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html):

```php
$isDevMode = true;
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration([__DIR__."/src"], $isDevMode);
```

The trick is now that the `Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration` method uses a `SimpleAnnotationReader` by default. You can change this behaviour by changing the fifth parameter to `false`:

```php
$isDevMode = true;
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration([__DIR__."/src"], $isDevMode, null, null, false);
```

This will force Doctrine to use the not-simple `AnnotationReader` which can handle your models now!

Comment: thank you, this helped me continue after being stuck for about 4 hours.. after adding the fifth parameter I was able to generate my entities!

Comment: it worked perfectly... this should be marked as the right answer!

Comment: s..t I spent hours trying to figure it out ;-)

Comment: I needed this too, can't understand why it's required and/or not part of the tutorial.

Comment: Ditto...saved me a ton of frustrations too :)

Comment: Very very helpful answer !

Comment: Can someone explain why this is needed? This works but I don't understand why.

Comment: The 5th parameter tells the ``createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration()`` function to use a different class to parse annotations. The default class is just a stupid choice.

Comment: Mark it as the correct answere. Also important: The latest documentation version (2018-01-29) recommends `use Doctrine\ORM\Annotation as ORM;` but `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;` must be used to work properly.

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR: Make sure the type of metadata you created matches the "create metadata configuration" method you used.**

I encountered the same problem while working through the Doctrine "Getting Started" guide. After looking through the Doctrine code a bit I figured out what was going wrong.  Basically, the code in the tutorial  in the "Obtaining the EntityManager" section is:

```php
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration([__DIR__ . "/src"], $isDevMode);
```

A little further in the tutorial, in the "Starting with the Product" section, it shows us how to set up the metadata, with an example for each of the possible options for this.  The tutorial says:

> Metadata for entities are configured using a XML, YAML or Docblock Annotations. This Getting Started Guide will show the mappings for all Mapping Drivers. References in the text will be made to the XML mapping.

Because of this statement, I decided to use the XML configuration.  Unfortunately, the `createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration` method in the tutorial code did not seem to be using the XML file I had created. (In hindsight, it seems much more obvious that this method is *specifically referring to annotation metadata, not XML metadata!*)

After I changed it to `createXMLMetadataConfiguration` instead, it worked as expected. So it looks like one possible source of this problem is that the "create metadata configuration" method you used may not match the type of metadata you created.

Comment: See http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html and consider using the path to /config/xml and not /src when you use the xml way.

Comment: This answer needs more upvotes as this applies to latest version

Answer (score 4):

Try clearing the cache:

```
sudo -u www-data php app/console cache:clear --env=dev
```

Comment: It seems your proposal is for when you are using symfony. What if not?

Answer (score 2):

Uncomment the one of the following lines in bootstrap.php:

```
// or if you prefer yaml or XML
//$config = Setup::createXMLMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/config/xml"), $isDevMode);
//$config = Setup::createYAMLMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/config/yaml"), $isDevMode);
```

Which depends if you created yaml or xml meta config files...

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with custom Doctrine installation. My solution was to re-set metadata driver:

```
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl(
    new Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver(
        new Doctrine\Common\Annotations\CachedReader(
            new Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader(),
            new Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache()
        ),
        ENTITY_DIR
    )
);
```

Solution from http://support.skipper18.com/1120/how-use-external-tools-generate-doctrine-getters-and-setters?show=1121#a1121
My scenario was [generating entities from existing database](https://jejakroda.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/generate-doctrine2-mappings-from-existing-database/)

The [newDefaultAnnotationDriver adds the namespace](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/c1943624ab1260c629316bab104dc5130c060154/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Configuration.php#L159) and the method comments state the following:

> If $useSimpleAnnotationReader is true, the notation `@Entity` will
>   work, otherwise, the notation `@ORM\Entity` will be supported.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when creating a new doctrine config in a new ZF2 module.

problem was caused by

`'User\Entity' => 'property_entities'`

the user part was from the old entity

`'Property\Entity' => 'property_entities'`

Changing that fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was with the number of asterisk used for the annotation

```
<?php

    namespace Models;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Annotation\{Id, Column, GeneratedValue, Entity};

    /** // I originally used one asterisk here and kept getting the error in question. Error disappeared after doubling the asterisk as it is in this answer
    * @Entity(repositoryClass="Doctrine\ORM\Annotation\Id")
    */
   class User {
   }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the XML mapping (using `Setup::createXMLMetadataConfiguration()`), you might want to pay attention to the following:

- That your XML mapping files **ends by** `.dcm.xml`, not only by `.xml`.
- That your XML file contains the full entity classname, inclusive of the namespace. For example, for a class `Company\Solution\Models\User`, you must have the `Company.Solution.Models.User.dcm.xml` mapping file in your XML path.

Answer (score 0):

you must add the docstring for example:

```
<?php
// src/User.php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;

}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try the following command:

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create
```

Comment: Could not open input file: vendor/bin/doctrine-module

Comment: I think you use composer for your project. Please try to install or update with composer. If nothing happened, try to rename your composer.lock to composer.lock.bak and retry to install. But if some errors ar thrown during the installation, remove the vendor folder an try again.