# Doctrine2: Getting Started Tutorial "No Metadata Classes to process"

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I've run through the first part of this tutorial three times now: 
And so far no amount of searching here or elsewhere has helped me make it work.

I get "No Metadata Classes to process." when I try

```
$ php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force --dump-sql
```

The Product.php file exists, and contains the Product class. I can echo the path referenced in bootstrap and that comes out fine.

Note that all code has been copy/pasted directly from the tutorial page (so I won't paste it in here for the sake of brevity).

If someone could run through the tutorial (it's pretty quick) and see if it works for them, and if not suggest where it's going wrong I will endeavour to feed that back to the Doctrine team so they can alter the documentation as appropriate.

When the intro tutorial is this hard to make work it's a definite barrier to entry!

Thanks all!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doctrine2 - No Metadata Classes to process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473225/doctrine2-no-metadata-classes-to-process)

Comment: Tried that one Phil - no dice. The fifth parameter didn't help, and the Product.php is already copy/pasted from the php tab.

Comment: Did you properly place your `Product.php` directly in the `src` folder ... as defined in the bootstrap.php: `$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src"), $isDevMode);`

Comment: sounds like the path to you models is not correct

Comment: You can try this. php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

Comment: Can you please add the link to what tutorial you are referring to in your post?