# Ambiguous Tutorial - Getting Started with Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to work through this tutorial.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html

But get stuck at the point where I have to create the schema.

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
```

Always getting:

> No Metadata Classes to process.

I tried the solutions presented by the following post in vain:

[Doctrine2 - No Metadata Classes to process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473225/doctrine2-no-metadata-classes-to-process)

and

[Doctrine2: Getting Started Tutorial "No Metadata Classes to process"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554483/doctrine2-getting-started-tutorial-no-metadata-classes-to-process)

Any suggestions ? I'm stuck here for about three hours :-/

Comment: Are you using doctrine by itself or with symfony2?

Comment: "doctrine/orm": "2.4.*" and "symfony/yaml": "2.*"

Comment: With symfony2 you can use `php app/console doctrine:schema:create` in the console (cmd), try it out

Comment: I have either app nor console folder

Comment: You need to do this in your symfony2 project (if you have one). So in the console `cd path/to/your/project/` then `php app/console doctrine:schema:create`. But this only works within a symfony 2 project, sadly i can't help you with standalone doctrine

Comment: The only occurrences of "orm:schema-tool:create" in the page you linked are a part where you're told:
<< At this point no entitiy metadata exists in src so you will see a message like “No Metadata Classes to process.” Don’t worry, we’ll create a Product entity and corresponding metadata in the next section. >>
Are you "at this point"? ;)

Comment: Check here :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473225/doctrine2-no-metadata-classes-to-process

Comment: @StockOverflaw, I read this, actually I'm at this point: php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force --dump-sql . There I'm getting the same result

Comment: Your entities may not be parsed due to erroneous annotations. The tutorial doesn't seem to mention that, but theoretically you should import the following for your entities to be properly parsed:

`use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;`

Plus, you'd have to prefix your annotations:

`@Entity` becomes `@ORM\Entity`, the same goes for `Table`, `Column`, `Id`, relations...

Comment: I solved it, but now trying to create the schema I'm getting:  [Doctrine\ORM\Tools\ToolsException]                                          
  Schema-Tool failed with Error 'could not find driver' while executing DDL:

Comment: Good thing! :) Just as a side note, it'd be nice that you validate your own answer and possibly enhance said answer so that people struggling with the same issue could find the solution quickly and easily! ;)

Comment: I provided an answer to my question, see below. And for the Doctrine\ORM\Tools\ToolsException , I just installed php5-sqlite

Answer (score 0):

> Metadata for entities are configured using a XML, YAML or Docblock
>   Annotations. This Getting Started Guide will show the mappings for all
>   Mapping Drivers. References in the text will be made to the XML
>   mapping.

Maybe I misunderstood. But when I read

> References in the text will be made to the XML mapping

I used the XML file to configure the metadata. But I should have used the **Docblock Annotations**, that's all I had to do.