# Zend - No Metadata CLasses to process

Tags: php, doctrine, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I'm facing an issue when trying to generate code with doctrine in command line.

```
./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:generate-entities --filter="pays" ./module/Application/src/ --generate-annotations=true
```

And I'm getting this response :

> No Metadata Classes to process.

I'm new to Zend and need help to know clearly what to do.

**Edit :**

I've checked this tutorial, and proceeded by creating the entity class with the following content :

```
namespace Mynamespace;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Table(name="pays")
* @ORM\Entity
*/

class Pays {

}
```

With this code, my command run successfully :

> Processing entity "Application\Entities\Pays"
>
> Entity classes generated to "C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\module\Application\src"

But unfortunately, I can't see any change inside the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doctrine2 - No Metadata Classes to process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473225/doctrine2-no-metadata-classes-to-process)

Comment: Not really a duplicate. I checked this [link](https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2013/04/10/zend-framework-2-generate-doctrine-entities-from-existing-database-using-doctrinemodule-and-doctrineormmodule/) but when generating entities, they're empty. There nothing inside. I don't how to use efficiently this.

Comment: Yes i know this error. It's really annoying. Let me check what was the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is coming from your config file not from your Entity.

Check your config file around your:

```
'default_orm_driver' => []
'orm_default' => []
```

And for myself i'm using Gedmo for translate descriptions

```
'translatable_entities' => []
```

Hope that helps someone